# How to make side by side tags bottom align with each other

Tags: html, css

I have encountered a problem when I am using html to develop a website. Basically, I have two div tags align side by side. However, when the content of the first div tag is too long, the content may take more than one line to be displayed. Since the content in the second div is quite short, it only need one line to be displayed.

```
<div style="float:left;width:80%;">XXX ... XXX</div>
<div align="right" style="float:right;width:20%;">YYY</div>
```

In this case, the end of the content does not align with each other. When I add one more (the third) div tag, the content will go after the first tag rather than start a new line. I have attached two images to show the problem and what I want from the solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: before adding the third div you should clear floating so it will start a new line: add something like `<br style="clear:both">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `style="clear:both"` on the third div.

```html
<div style="float:left; width: 80%">text 1<br>text 1</div>
<div style="float:right; width: 20%">text 2</div>
<div style="clear:both">text 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add an extra `<div>`, and apply the style `clear both` to it

```css
.one {
  width: 48%;
  margin-right:2%;
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.three {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"> div 1 </div>
<div class="two"> div 2 </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="three"> div 3 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try use this:

```css
#container .col-1 {width: 20%;}
#container .col-2 {width: 40%;}
#container .col-3 {width: 60%;}
#container .col-4 {width: 80%;}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 75%;
}
#container > div {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tag-1 col-4">
    <h1>Tag 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tag-2 col-1">
    <h1>Tag 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="tag-3">
    <h1>Tag 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Floated elements, effect their siblings and this floated behaviors needs to remove otherwise it might leads to many issues as you mentioned. Also parent of floated element doesn't take height until unless floating behavior is cleared. 
Modern browser handles it for us but still we should write a clean code.

We can clear floated effect as:

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div style="float:left;width:80%;">XXX ... XXX</div>
  <div align="right" style="float:right;width:20%;">YYY</div>
</div>
```